# Keras Output Dimensions of VGG19 Conv4-1 Layer doesn't match up with model output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
```

To create the VGG19 model I use:

```
img = Input(shape=(256,256,3))
vgg = VGG19(weights="imagenet")
vgg.outputs = [vgg.get_layer('block4_conv1').output]
model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=vgg(img))
```

Then in the `model.summary()` I see that:

`block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160`

My expected dimensions are `(28,28,512)`.

To load the image into the network I use:

```
img = image.load_img("./path-to-image.jpeg", target_size=(256, 256))
img = preprocess_input(np.array(img))
```

However, when I put my image through the model, my output dimension is `(1, 32, 32, 512)` and it makes no sense as to why this happens!

To get output dimensions I run:

```
img_out = \
    model.predict(
        np.expand_dims(img, 0), 
        batch_size=1
    )

img_out.shape
>>> (1, 32, 32, 512) != (28,28,512)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VGG19 takes input (224, 224, 3) by default. If you apply 3 max-pooling layers to it, you will get (28,28, num_kernels).

But, your input is (256, 256, 3). So, if you apply 3 max-pooling layers to this, you will end up getting (32, 32, num_kernels).

After 1st max-pool layer - (128, 128, num_kernels)
After 2nd max-pool layer - (64, 64, num_kernels)
After 3rd max-pool layer - (32, 32, num_kernels)